# Can we connect dial into Twilio Programmable Video Group Rooms?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-video

It seems Twilio Programmable Video API is based on WebRTC. This will allow us to setup audio/video conference from browser/app to browser/app.

However, is there any way to connect Programmable Voice incoming audio calls to the Video rooms? Also is there any way to make outgoing Voice calls from the Rooms?

This will allow a participant to just dial-in even if his internet is not working.

Comment: Check this more recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327729/can-i-combine-programmable-video-with-a-voice-call?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is not currently possible, using the Video SDK, to dial into a Video Group Room from an audio call over the phone network. If that changes I will update this answer.