# Can I combine programmable video with a voice call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

Is it possible to include a "programmable voice" call into a "programmable video" room?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, more details here.

[Now You Can Add Programmable Voice Participants to Video Group Rooms](https://www.twilio.com/blog/now-you-can-add-programmable-voice-participants-video-group-rooms)